# Where is the correct place in Inno Setup to perform these actions?

Tags: inno-setup

During my install I need to perform some code:

1. Delete an existing file in the app folder if it exists.
2. Read a registry key to see if they are using local help.
3. If they are using local help then prompt to download the help file.
4. If they answer yes, then download.
5. If they answer no, then update the registry key to say it is using online help.

Which step or event should I use in the code section to perform these tasks?

Is it CurStepChanged() / ssInstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do the detection/prompting *before* the installation starts. You may use a custom page or a conditional task.

And the actual actions can be done in `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`.